# Using 2 Javascripts on one page

Tags: javascript

I added a javascript menu to my website (see link below)
alpineglass.biz/alpinesample.html

and I am trying to add a pop up request form from jotform.com.

When I add the two javascripts to my page, the menu pictures stick when you scrollover and don't show the sub menus. (see link below)
alpineglass.biz/contactus.html

**How do I get both to work?**

Here is the code for the menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            /**
            * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
            * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
            * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
            * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
            * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
            */
            $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                $elem.find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'170px',
                        'height':'170px',
                        'left':'0px'
                     },400,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length){
                        var left = '170px';
                        if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                            left = '-170px';
                        $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
                    }   
                });
            }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                if($sub_menu.length)
                    $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

                $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                     .andSelf().find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'0px',
                        'height':'0px',
                        'left':'85px'},400)
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the code for the jotform javascript:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jotfor.ms/static/feedback2.js?3.1.349" type="text/javascript">
new JotformFeedback({
formId:'31116060957147',
base:'http://jotform.us/',
windowTitle:'Request a FREE quote',
background:'#50A351',
fontColor:'#FFFFFF',
type:false,
height:500,
width:500
});
</script>
<a class="lightbox-31116060957147" style="cursor:pointer;color:black;text-decoration:underline;">[Request FREE Quote]</a>
```

Comment: There's likely to be a conflict. The only way to fix it is through debugging step-by-step what goes wrong, using the error console to see what error messages appear.

Comment: Can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) where we can reproduce?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSFiddle.